# Draw a line when user touch the Uiimageview

Tags: ipad

i am working on a project in which i have added a UIimageview to show an image selected by user. Now requirement is that if user want to crop an images  it can touch the image according to crop requirement. when user cropping the image a line should draw at place where user has touched. i know that UITouch class will use for it. But i am unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possible solutions.

1) Create a custom UIView that contains a UIImageView as it's subview.  Make the UIImageView be the same size as the custom UIView.  Then add code to detect the touches on the custom UIView and draw the lines on top of the UIImageView subview.

2) Create a custom clone of UIImageView that draws the image first as the 'background' and then detects the touches and draws the lines on top of the image.

Also make sure you have userInteractionEabled set to YES on the view receiving the touches.